# Jolt: How to merge in one array elements from different arrays

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I'm trying to merge the content from different elements in an array.

My jSon looks like this:

```
{
  "Messages": {
    "test": "test1",
    "CreditCheck": [
      {
        "name": "Credit Score",
        "score": 15,
        "percentage": 20
      },
      {
        "name": "Cards Score",
        "score": 15,
        "percentage": 20
      },
      {
        "name": "Bank Score",
        "score": 20,
        "percentage": 20
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My current Jolt Spec is this one:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "test": "myTesting",
        "CreditCheck": {
          "*": {
            "name": "creditName.[]",
            "score": "creditScore.[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And I'm getting the following:

```
{
  "myTesting" : "test1",
  "creditName" : [ "Credit Score", "Cards Score", "Bank Score" ],
  "creditScore" : [ 15, 15, 20 ]
}
```

But what I need to achieve is the following:

```
{
  "myTesting" : "test1",
  "creditNames&Scores" : [ "Credit Score": 15, "Cards Score": 15, "Bank Score": 20 ],
}
```

There's not a predefined number of elements in "CreditCheck" structure so I'm trying to do it as dynamic as possible.

Thanks in advance for the help, bests !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This spec should work for you:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "test": "myTesting",
        "CreditCheck": {
          "*": {
            "score": "creditNames\\&Scores[].@1,name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The output:

```json
{
  "myTesting": "test1",
  "creditNames&Scores": [
    {
      "Credit Score": 15
    },
    {
      "Cards Score": 15
    },
    {
      "Bank Score": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

Notes:

- The elements in the output have to be wrapped in curly braces to make them valid json objects
- `\\` is used to escape the ampersand `&`
- Tested with https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ where you can also find [the example](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#transposeComplex) of the [advanced `@` wildcard](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java#L324) usage

Comment: I will really appreciate if you [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/630212), then. Cheers!

Comment: I did! I voted but it's not displayed  because my reputation is lower than 15.

Comment: Thanks! You can also click the checkmark below it, [see the picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/630212). Accepting the answer will give you +2 points.